# how to change the result to 0 when the result is NULL in sql statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement, sth like..

```
select col1, col2, col3 from tbl1 where (conditions)
```

If there is no row,

All I see is..

```
NULL,NULL,NULL
```

What I want to get is

```
0,0,0
```

I know there is sth like..

```
select when (condition) then RESULT else 0 end as 'Col1',..... from tbl1
```

But if i Do that, I have to check condition everyline..

Any better idea??

Comment: If there's no row, you won't see NULLs -- there won't be any such rows in the result set.

Comment: sry.. if I didn't explain more, Theer will b a line since my first value is 'No Appointment' as 'Col1', sum(......) as 'Col2',...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select isnull(col1,0) from tbl1
```

Another approach, if you intend to get 1 row but didn't get any, you can use the sum coalesce approach:

```
select coalesce(sum(col1),0) from tbl1
```

Another one, use WITH so you don't have to re-evaluate rows when filtering don't produce any results:

```
with result as
(
    select col1, col2, col3 from tbl1 
    where 1 = 0 -- your condition goes here
)
select col1, col2, col3 from result
union
select 0, 0, 0 where not exists(select * from result)
```

Comment: the corrrect syntax is isnull(col1, 0)

Comment: thanks, it's written in a haste, i corrected the isnull(col1) to isnull(col1,0) now

Answer (score 0):

For this type of queries u can use nvl function of sql. Syntax given below..

```
Nvl( null value colum,0)
```

example-- like if one employe dont get the comisition then query wl be..

```
Select  nvl( cmsn_pct,0) from employee;
```